# Customizing wordpress static home page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i purchased  this  wordpress theme  [Clinico](http://clinico.creaws.com/) , This is using Static   page for  home page and  . for me Problem is that its coded using Some  massive JS libraries and every thing is done  in really complex style .  in home page i have to remove a section that  i am unable to find how its being generated   when i go to  theme customize options it says its using "A Static page " and in drop down  its named as "HOME" now  there is no home.php or any thing else in folder  how do i  edit   this static page ?   is it  index.php ? as removing most of the code from index.php is not working to remove that section

Please help

Comment: please check in page-templates folder

Comment: Check the theme headers (commented out template name at the top of the .php page) The name is what you see in the dropdown on the backend

Comment: @atmd sorry i did not understand ?

Comment: See James Waddington's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally Wordpress static pages use page.php for their template.
You can [create your own page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) by copying page.php and adding a header comment at the top like this:

```
/*
 * Template Name: AName
 */
```

You will then be able to select the name of your template in the Wordpress editor. Doing it this way allows you to have different templates for different pages, and keep the original theme template in tact in case you want to use it later.

Hope that helps.